# Drupal - alt tags on images

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm using Drupal 7, notably the `Image` field and the `Media file selector` widget to upload images.

The biggest problem is that these images do not have `alt` tags when viewing the HTML source on the frontend.

Is there a way to display such images to have the `alt` on images?

Thanks

EDIT:

I am using a custom theme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit the Image field for your content type by navigating to `admin/structure/types/manage/[my-content-type]/fields/field_image`.

Make sure both the "Enable Alt field" and "Enable Title field" are checked. 
In my case, "Enable Alt field" was checked for me by default, but I had to check "Enable Title field" in order to get the alt text field to show up on the node add/edit form. Weird.

Comment: Brilliant. I was using the 'Media File Selector'. Changing the widget to image worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The related issue queue is http://drupal.org/node/1307054 and I believe that there is a recent fix which should get into the next release.